# как поймать ошибку, вызванную внутри WebWorker?

Tags: javascript, webworkers

```js
void function worker() {
 window.onerror = () => {
  console.log('windowError')
 }
 const code = `//-->
 this.onerror = () => {
  console.log('insideError')
 }
 throw new TypeError('qwa');
 // <--`
 const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([code],{ type: 'text/javascript' }))
 const worker = new Worker(url)
 worker.onerror = () => {
  console.log('workerError')
 }
}()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разве в worker.onerror не передается сама ошибка? worker.onerror = e => console.log(e)

Comment: так вот и я не пойму, везде где можно написал `onerror` а консоль говорит `uncaught` (см.скрины) можно просто скопировать код, вставить в консоль браузера нажать энтер и посмотреть на это своими глазами : )